# liquibase maven plugin UUID vs BINARY(255)

Tags: java, maven, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate, liquibase-sql

- I use the liquibase-maven-plugin to generate the database migration scripts.
- But liquibase generates the UUID id fields as BINARY(255).
- This in itself is not a problem as the IDs for new entities are generated by hibernate.
  So database support for uuid is not required.
- but my problem now are the sample data in csv files, in which I have to insert the uuid as binary.

So I see 2 possible solutions for my problem:

1. let liquibase-maven-plugin generate the UUID fields as real UUID database fields.
2. tell liquibase to transform the uuid in my csv files into binary before inserting.

**Does anyone know how to perform either 1. or 2. ?**

**Or is there even a 3. option I am not aware of ?**

java entity

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private UUID id;
  @Column
  private String name;
}
```

change set generated by liquibase-maven-plugin

```
- changeSet:
    id: 1638440755794-7
    changes:
    - createTable:
        columns:
        - column:
            constraints:
              nullable: false
              primaryKey: true
            name: id
            type: BINARY(255)
        - column:
            name: name
            type: VARCHAR(255)
        tableName: test_entity
```

sample-data.csv - *NOT WORKING*

```
id,name
0da87def-2d39-47f1-ae4a-310fc37a8aa0,meinName
```

sample-data.csv - *WORKING*

```
id,name
Dah97y05R/GuSjEPw3qKoA==,meinName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced the same problem when using PostgreSQL. I decided by specifying an explicit dialect in the liquibase-maven-plugin settings.

```
<referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:ru.mts.iot.core.metainvsrv.entity?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect</referenceUrl>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like as of version 3.6 Liquibase supports UUIDs:

https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/working-with-uuids.html

Comment: thanks for your reply. I know that liquibase supports UUIDs. But the liquibase-maven-plugin generates the field as a binary(255) even though the entities id attribute is of type UUID.